# mysqldump not exporting views correctly

Tags: mysql

For taking backup i run below command :

```
mysqldump -u root -p database_name > database_name.sql
```

All tables are getting dump correctly but views are like below:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `VwAdminNewYearBookings`;
/!50001 DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `VwAdminNewYearBookings`/;
SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client;
SET character_set_client = utf8;
/*!50001 CREATE VIEW `VwAdminNewYearBookings` AS SELECT 
 1 AS `customer_id`,
 1 AS `STATUS`,
 1 AS `SlotId`,
 1 AS `id`,
 1 AS `numberOfPeople`,
 1 AS `archanas`,
 1 AS `archana_amount`,
 1 AS `name`,
 1 AS `email`,
 1 AS `phone`,
 1 AS `apptdate`,
 1 AS `slotstart`,
 1 AS `slotend`,
 1 AS `paymentStatus`,
 1 AS `first_name`,
 1 AS `last_name`,
 1 AS `cart_id`,
 1 AS `slottype`*/;
SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client;
```

Any help appreciated.